# In R I need to add two elements from two different columns into a third column with a for loop

Tags: r

I have three columns, two of which have numerical values for 10 rows and one open column for the sum of the other two.

I am trying to add c1 + c2 = c3 using a for-loop

Comment: `df$c3 <- df$c1 + df$c2` should do it.

Comment: What kind of data structure do you have? If you have a data frame then Sagar's comment will do without the need of a for loop.

Comment: There could be 2 reasons you're getting voted down. First, you are not supposed to use a for-loop to add vectors (try: `(c3 <- c1 + c2)`). Second, you only have to switch the left-hand and the right hand side `c3 = c1 + c2`, (You could even try `c1 + c2 -> c3`). Good luck.

Comment: yeah thanks for that! It is a data frame, but I want to do it with a for loop also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here is one proposition. First, let's assume that df is your data frame with 2 first columns with some noise(random numbers from a normal distribution), plus a third column with only zeros:

`df <- data.frame(var1=rnorm(10),var2=rnorm(10),var3=numeric(length = 10))`

To get the result as you wish, you can simply try (as mentioned on the comments):
   `df$var3<-df$var1+df$var2`

However, if you want it with the for loop try the following:

```
for(j in 1:10)
 {
    df$var3[j] <- df$var1[j]+df$var2[j]
 }
 print(df)
```

Hopefully, it will help.